# OpenCV equivalent for Matlab's rdivide?

Tags: matlab, opencv

For example we have expression using [rdivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) in Matlab:

```
  B = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, A(4,:));
```

How can we write equavalent expression for opencv?

Opencv has [divide](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#divide) function, but seems it can't be used for matrix with different dimensions:

```
Mat t1= Mat::ones(2,3,CV_64FC1);
Mat t2= Mat::ones(1,3,CV_64FC1);
Mat dst;
divide(t1,t2,dst);
```

this don't work, so we need to replicate one row to matrix to match dimensions of t1 or use divide with 1 row in cycle.

My solution for opencv(A modified inplace):

```
for(int i=0;i<A.rows;++i)
{
    divide(A.row(i),A.row(3),A.row(i));
}
```

Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Does the openCV code produce the same result? As soon as you reached i=3 it is modified and all further rows are divided by this row. At least if I read your code right (never used OpenCV)

Comment: @Daniel 3 is last row.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`repeat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#repeat) function of OpenCV to replicate a matrix.

The equivalent OpenCV code for the above mentioned MATLAB command is following:

```
cv::Mat B = A/cv::repeat(A.row(3),4,1);
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @sgarizvi solution, you may find this wrapper to Matlab `rdivide` helpful:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


Mat rdivide(const Mat& A, const Mat& B)
{
    int nx = A.cols / B.cols;
    int ny = A.rows / B.rows;
    return A / repeat(B, ny, nx);
}

Mat rdivide(const Mat& A, double d)
{
    return A / d;
}


int main()
{
    Mat1f A = (Mat1f(3, 5) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
    Mat B = rdivide(A, A.row(2)); // Divide by matrix, works also for cols: e.g. A.col(2)
    Mat C = rdivide(A, 2);        // Divide by scalar

    cout << "A: " << endl << A << endl << endl;
    cout << "B: " << endl << B << endl << endl;
    cout << "C: " << endl << C << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```